# PHP fsockopen not working for non port 80

Tags: php, fsockopen

I have a simple PHP script. It works for any external IP on port 80 but any other port fails. I'm assuming it has to do with the host, so what am I missing to be able to check ports other than 80?

Comment: Talk to your host, who may be willing to make an exception for your account. Are you on a shared host?

Comment: Yes it's shared hosting. I expected that to be the problem, just needed to identify the culprit.

Comment: Try high ports (over 1024), if you are able to change the port on the other side of the connection. These are sometimes not as restricted as the reserved ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most hosting systems prevent outgoing connections on other ports than 80 to prevent abuse, for example botscripts connecting to IRC servers or spamscripts connecting to SMTP hosts on 25.

[Example hoster explanation](https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/152).